# Android index scrolling

Tags: android, scroll

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/scrolling.html

I'm looking for solution to perform the second part ("Index Scrolling"), but I can't find any examples to do that.
Is there a solution in default-API?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To implement index scrolling, you have to call `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` on your ListView. In addition, your adapter has to implement the [`SectionIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) interface.

You can find an example here: http://spinettaro.blogspot.de/2011/11/android-snippet-code-android-listview.html

This should work with all Views that are a subclass of `AbsListView`.

Comment: Great, I have just one question. How can I make scroll track thin? I've tried to set custom track but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Sample code posted in GitHub. Check out this,

https://github.com/rno/Android-ScrollBarPanel

Comment: Thanks, but I think that there should be much easier solution for the functionality that is presented on android-developers