# list view navigation just like in android contacts view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a really basic question about the android list view element. I have a list view with about 100 elements. To simplify the navigation, I would like to use a 'list view navigation bar' as marked in the image below

[image: list view navigation bar]

I searched for it but I still don't know if this is a standard view or not. I guess not. And if not, how might this smart list view navigation be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout this

> [Android index scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717463/android-index-scrolling)

and this

> http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html

i have not used them, just searched it